# Проблема с Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: Данная проблема:]

Кто сталкивался? И какие возможны методы устранения? Заранее спасибо.
UPD:Проблему решил перенацеливанием проекта в студии.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки и релевантный код. не картинки

Comment: @VTT, там около 400 ошибок, в коде ошибок нет. Они в студии.

Comment: @krax1337: Значение имеет только самая первая ошибка. А вам скриншот - никому не нужная бессмыслица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается перенацеливанием проекта в студии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]